# How to handle ctrl+arrow in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, keyboard-shortcuts

I've noticed an problem when trying to catch keyboard shortcut: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + an arrow.

I've handled keydown event. Now when I hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key then keydown event is fired once. If I hold an arrow (so that now I'm holding <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + an arrow) it doesn't fire another event. Is it forbidden from any reason? I guess I've already encountered this problem in Opera a few years ago and there was an option for it in browser.

My results:

- holding <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, press an arrow -- fires event for <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and doesn't fire an event for an arrow
- press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + an arrow at once  -- fires one event but only with keycode of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>.
- holding <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, press a letter (eg. <kbd>S</kbd>) -- works as expected
- press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + letter (eg. <kbd>S</kbd>) -- works as expected

(Results are identical in Chrome and Firefox. Is the behaviour described above a standard?)

I'm using:

- `function OnKeyDown(e) { }`
- `e.ctrlKey`, e.which properties of event

The question is: what might be the problem?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should check if the [`event.ctrlKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.ctrlKey) flag is true, something like this:

```
document.getElementById('element').onkeydown = function (e) { 
  e = e || window.event;
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which,
      arrow = {left: 37, up: 38, right: 39, down: 40 };

  if (e.ctrlKey) {
    switch (keyCode) {
      case arrow.left:
      //... handle Ctrl-LeftArrow
      break;
      //...
    }
  }
};
```

Check an example [here](http://jsbin.com/ivefo3/3/).

Comment: I'm checking event.ctrlKey. I wrote it in my question. I tried your code: http://pastebin.org/168399 - and it doesn't work - maybe something is wrong with my keyboard.

Comment: I posted the code to pastebin because I don't know how else respond to your answer with such a long code (comment is too short, adding the code as answer is kind of rude, adding the code to the question is non-systematic). *CONFUSED*

Comment: I'm playing [here](http://jsbin.com/ojaki3) with the code you posted, and it works properly, if *LeftArrow* (without Ctrl) is pressed it alets "gosh", if *Ctrl* - *LeftArrow*, alerts "heureka"...

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Maybe the problem is really in my keyboard. I'm not sure. But thank you!

Comment: It's really a matter of keyboard driver, I've installed another and it partially works. I'm sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: It is worth noting that *this does not work on a mac*